# Zend Debugger Extension Is Not Loading Correctly

Tags: php, php-extension, zend-debugger

I'm on windows 7 with PHP 5.4.4 TS. I'm trying to load the zend debugger extension, it's the last line on my PHP.ini file:

```
[Zend]
zend_extension_ts = C:\php\ext\ZendDebugger.dll
zend_debugger.allow_hosts = 127.0.0.1/32,192.168.0.1/32,10.0.0.0/8
zend_debugger.expose_remotely = always
```

The extension doesn't show up when I call the phpinfo() section. There is nothing in the error logs though. The extension that I am using is for PHP 5.3 though so that may be why it's not loading properly. Does anyone know if there is a TS version for PHP 5.3+ ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with PHP 5.4.11. It looks like thread safe versions of ZendDebugger.dll are no longer available. Using zend_extension (instead of zend_extension_ts) with ZendDebugger.dll for 5.3.x (max version I could find) did not work for me either.

In the end I solved the problem by switching to xdebug from xdebug.org. Downloaded php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll from http://xdebug.org/download.php and adjusted php.ini as:

```
zend_extension="C:\php_5_4_11\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll"
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always

xdebug.remote_enable=on
xebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```